# How to connect my React app to a backend with which is different origin

Tags: node.js, reactjs, https, proxy, react-router

**Hello Experts**

My problem is I am developing a react js application with some Axios call, I am connecting my serverside backend (which is an indifferent location like a real IP address)  with writing a proxy in **package.json** which is  working on my pc is fine,

But when I am going to deploy my application on AWS in production mode, unfortunately, the backend is not connecting (Maybe proxy is not working as I learn by google search ), in this situation what should I do to connect my react js app with my backend

please help me if you can thanx in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Usually browsers block cross-origin request by default.

Please check **cors** npm package to whitelist/allow requests from your react app to backend server.

link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Hope this helps. :)